# What's the proper way to find and remove duplicate images from posts and the media library?

Tags: images, media-library, duplicates

I just exported a largish WP blog from MediaTemple to PHPFog.

I used the standard WordPress export and import plugins.

For some unknown reason all of my media assets have been duplicated. I now have twice as many images per post.

If an original file was called "Lot-44-Warrens.jpg" it now has a duplicate called "Lot-44-Warrens1.jpg" Both files are attached to the same post.

I now have many duplicate images across about 250+ posts.

So my question is how do I remove said duplicates from the media library and from the posts?

I tried to search the media library with "*1.jpg", but it didn't work.

Looking for a neat solution that doesn't mean removing each dupe manually.

Perhaps there is a MySQL query I can run to remove the dupes from the library and the posts?

The site in question is: http://igrealty.phpfogapp.com/ .

Comment: Could you delete them all and reimport?

Comment: Tried that 4 times last night. Every time they imported with dupes. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

combining the two answer on this page, I found this worked.

```
$args = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
));

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while($loop->have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  $args2 = array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image');
    $attachments = get_posts($args2);
    if($attachments) {
      foreach ($attachments as $img_post) {
        if( ((strpos($img_post->guid, '1.jpg')!== false) || (strpos($img_post->guid, '1.gif')!== false) || (strpos($img_post->guid, '1.png')!== false))){
          $stuff = $img_post->guid;
          wp_delete_attachment($img_post->ID);
        } 
      }
    }
} wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I must try that

Comment: @jnthnclrk I had some issued importing images and it duplicated 2000+ of them, this did the trick in getting rid of the duplicates. Test it out first 5 or so posts, also though it works, I just noticed one or two errors with the loop which I'll edit now.

Answer (score 5):

Use a run-once script to clean it up. Just an outline, no code:

1. Get all posts. See [`get_posts( array ( 'numberposts' => -1 ) )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)
2. For each post get all attachments. See [`get_children( array ( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1 ) )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children)
3. For each attachment get the attachment URL. See [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)
4. If you find the attachment URL in the parent post's content (`$post->post_content`):

   - If there is another attachment URL with the same file name plus the `1` and
   - both are part of the post content then
   - remove the second image first then
   - use [`wp_delete_attachment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment) to delete the physical file. This will remove all meta data and all associations in other posts too. It is the best way to remove attached files (imho).

This may take a while. Test it on a local copy of your site. Maybe you should run the process in steps of 50 posts (`'numberposts' => 50`).

Comment: Not sure why the bounty got awarded. This didn't actually work for me at all.

Comment: Sorry to read that. It happened due to the votes. See the [bounty FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) for details.

Comment: Ah well. No biggie.

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up, but it seems you've glossed over the meat of the question. For instance I need to the details of 4a, b and c.

Answer (score 4):

This script will grab all of the attachments in the database, compare the file to one another through md5 and if it finds a duplicate and it has a 1 at the end of the file name it will remove the image:

```
require('wp-load.php');

global $wpdb;

$img_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type like 'attachment'");

$img_md5s = array();

foreach($img_posts as $img_post){
  $single_img_md5 = md5_file($img_post->guid);

  if(in_array($single_img_md5, $img_md5s) && ((strpos($img_post->guid, '1.jpg')!== false) || (strpos($img_post->guid, '1.gif')!== false) || (strpos($img_post->guid, '1.png')!== false))){
    wp_delete_attachment($img_post->ID);

  }else{
    $img_md5s[] = $single_img_md5;
  }
}
```

Just place it in a file in your root directory.

Comment: You might want to run the script and print out the img's guid to see how accurate it is first then if you like the results, run the script with wp_delete_attachment.

Comment: Won't work, as it is missing the `$wpdb` function for `$image_post`. Further `$wpdb->("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type like 'attachment'");` should be: `$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE post_type LIKE %s", $wpdb->posts, like_escape( '%attachment%' ) ) );`...

Comment: Yeah, I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /var/fog/apps/24741/igrealty.phpfogapp.com/find-dupes.php on line 6

Comment: Now getting this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/fog/apps/24741/igrealty.phpfogapp.com/find-dupes.php on line 11

Comment: Instead of $wpdb->query try $wpdb->get_results

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/fog/apps/24741/igrealty.phpfogapp.com/find-dupes.php on line 11

Comment: Try print_r($img_posts); right before the foreach loop and see if there is anything in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I learn't a valuable lesson yesterday, if an application does not provide you with adequate functions for finding and removing assets from a database, and you're trying to find duplicates across multiple, often unique, fields, and you're unsure how to create complex MySQL queries; then the best bet is to go back to basics.

In the end, I exported the tables with dupes into Excel, filtered them by creating my own "hash" of significant fields ( doing this in MySQL was complex and crashed the server a few times ) and pruned the data set so that I created a list of IDs that I was absolutely sure I wanted to remove. I then built a much more simple MySQL query to delete each row by ID.

This method worked great because I was able to take things slowly and consider each Excel filter I applied. This way I was much more confident I was deleting the correct records. I also have an accurate record in Excel of exactly what I did delete.

Comment: MySql and PHP are much more sophisticated and advanced than Excel or any other spreadsheet program. You just don't have the right skills to implement the solution with them.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.